# Delete a record using RandomAccessFile

Tags: java

what i currently able to do for deleting a record from my .txt file is to put all the characters as empty but unfortunately it just make make those unit as empty and it will not remove those units. do you have any idea how can i completely delete a row of record from my txt file without rewriting the whole file again ?

```
protected boolean DeleteObject(int mID)
{
    try {
        file = new RandomAccessFile(new File("UserDB.txt"), "rw");
        long FileSize = file.length();
        file.seek(0);
        long NUMRecords = FileSize / RECORD;
        for (int j=0; j < NUMRecords; j++) {

            sID = file.readUTF();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10 - sID.length(); i++) {
                file.readByte();
            }
            ID = Integer.parseInt(sID);

            fName = file.readUTF();
            for (int i = 0; i < 20 - fName.length(); i++) {
                file.readByte();
            }

            surname = file.readUTF();
            for (int i = 0; i < 20 - surname.length(); i++) {
                file.readByte();
            }

            sMajor = file.readUTF();
            for(int i=0; i<3-sMajor.length(); i++){
                file.readByte();
            }
            major = Integer.parseInt(sMajor);

            if(ID == mID)
            {
                file.seek(j*RECORD);
                for(int k =0; k<RECORD; k++)
                {
                    file.writeUTF("");
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("ERROR IN DELETING FILE "+e);
        e.getStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("Nothing Found");
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Truncating the mid part of a file isn't supported on the major platforms, that means, even if java had a method to do that, it would still require rewriting of the part of the file. Even harder would be doing this atomically.

Comment: @Ferrybig on which platforms is this supported?

Answer (score 1):

You could design your file to contain a logical delete flag.
When deleting the record you would then update the logical delete flag, marking the record as deleted rather than physically removing it from the file.

Answer (score 1):

I once had a file intended as a queue. The concept is that deleting always occurred linearly since it is a queue. So the deleting process would just rewrite the file offset of the next non-deleted row.

I reserved the first 8 bytes of the file as a file pointer (whose value was 8 or above). This makes the file binary though, not txt anymore. You could write that offset in a sibling file though.

However, this being a queue, I had to create new files from time to time and garbecollect the entirely deleted ones.

Otherwise, no you cannot cut away a file portion. Each row must have it's own delete flag. And vacuuming/packing/managing free space (or rewriting a clean version) is a sad reality for every database out there.

Comment: "I once had a file intended as a queue. The concept is that deleting always occurred linearly since it is a queue. So the deleting process would just rewrite the file offset of the next non-deleted row." this would be a great idea, how can i rewrite the next row into the item that i want to delete ? by doing this way, we can shift everything up and then reduce the size of the txt file using setLength() function.

Comment: Oh, you wouldn't want to do that. This would mean essentially the same as rewriting the whole file minus one record.

Comment: If you have fixed length records, that is another game: you can easily treat this file like a drum, where the said pointer is the head, and you would also have a tail pointer and write the file at the tail. But since you are not clear about the purpose of the db.txt, (queue or not), it may lead to other complications. Out of order deletes will turn you file into a largely fragmented blob for which you have to manage the deleted space...

Comment: FYI, your problem looks identical to an email folder. like in Thunderbird. "Compact folders" should be called eventually to pack and remove all deleted emails.